# How to reset value of Ion Select in Ionic 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I want to reset `ion-select` value to empty. I am navigating to another page after selection and when i click back button from that page `ion-select` has that value selected. I want it reset that ion-select on back button.

Here is my .html file code

```
<ion-select #mySelect style="display: none" (ionChange)="onOrderSelection($event)" interface="action-sheet" mode="ios" [value]="orderTypeModel">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of orderTypes" [value]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
```

And here is Component Code

```
orderTypeModel = '';
ionViewWillEnter(): void {
  this.orderTypeModel = null;
  this.changeDetecRef.detectChanges();
}
```

I have also tried `[ngModel]` in place of `[value]` but event that is not working.

Please suggest some way to do that?

Comment: your code works fine with both `[value]` and `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

add ngModel to ion-select :

**<ion-select [(ngModel)]="MyselectItem">**

and when you want to reset it like this:

**this.MyselectItem = null;**